# Как сделать блок скролящимся независимо от остальных?

Tags: html, css

Суть проблемы такова: есть страница, на которой правый блок с классом `all` должен скроллить картинки. При этом вся остальная страница должна оставаться статичной. Как это реализовать?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Adineue;
  src: url("fonts/adineue.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ABold;
  src: url("fonts/adineue-bold.ttf");
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  font-size: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #141516;
}

header .header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

header .logo {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
}

header .lang {
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-header {
  z-index: 3;
}

.navbar-header .toggle-button {
  height: 5vh;
  width: 5vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  z-index: 3;
}

.navbar-header .toggle-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar+.bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.middle {
  top: 11px;
}

.bottom {
  top: 22px;
}

.toggle-active .bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.toggle-active .top {
  transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}

.toggle-active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle-active .bottom {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(87, 87, 87, 0.56);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, height 0.35s;
}

.overlay .rofas-nav {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 3vh;
  left: 10vw;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay .info-nav {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 10vw;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.overlay ul li a span {
  font-family: 'ABold';
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.nav-active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

.roof-link:hover {
  color: #e64e4e;
}

.fasad-link:hover {
  color: #f7a550;
}

.design-link:hover {
  color: #fedd32;
}

.industry-link:hover {
  color: #51b9f1;
}

.eco-link:hover {
  color: #70ca57;
}

.stone-link:hover {
  color: #956ccc;
}

.roof {
  color: #e64e4e;
}

.fasad {
  color: #f7a550;
}

.design {
  color: #fedd32;
}

.industry {
  color: #51b9f1;
}

.eco {
  color: #70ca57;
}

.stone {
  color: #956ccc;
}

.slider {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("../images/roof-bg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slider-content {
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.slider_content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 3vw;
}

.slider_content span {
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  font-size: 1em;
}

.slider-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.slider-text h1 {
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.slider-text span {
  color: #e64e4e;
  font-family: 'ABold';
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.slider-text p {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 0.825em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.object-container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.all {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.for-all {
  width: 36vw;
  height: 33.4vh;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.first {
  background-image: url("../images/ruukki.png");
}

.second {
  background-image: url("../images/cheker.png");
}

.third {
  background-image: url("../images/bitum.png");
}

.fourth {
  background-image: url("../images/elems.png");
}

.fifth {
  background-image: url("../images/falz.png");
}

.sixth {
  background-image: url("../images/gidro.png");
}

.seventh {
  background-image: url("../images/mansard.png");
}

.eigth {
  background-image: url("../images/metalo.png");
}

.nineth {
  background-image: url("../images/samorez.png");
}

.tenth {
  background-image: url("../images/vodostok.png");
}

.right-side {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.btn:hover {
  filter: opacity(0.1);
}

.btn-roof {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.btn-roof:hover {
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/grids-responsive-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="pure-g">
  <header style="display: none" id="header" class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1 pure-u-md-1 pure-u-lg-1-12">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="toggle-button" id="toggle">
          <span class="bar top"></span>
          <span class="bar middle"></span>
          <span class="bar bottom"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <ul class="rofas-nav">
          <li><a href="slide1.html">Rofas <span class="roof-link">Roof</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right roof arrow-right-roof"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="slide2.html">Rofas <span class="fasad-link">Фасад</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right fasad arrow-right-fasad"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="slide3.html">Rofas <span class="design-link">Design</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right design arrow-right-design"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="slide4.html">Rofas <span class="industry-link">Industry</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right industry arrow-right-industry"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="slide5.html">Rofas <span class="eco-link">Eco</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right eco arrow-right-eco"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="slide6.html">Rofas <span class="stone-link">Stone</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right stone arrow-right-stone"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="info-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Блог</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Партнёры</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="dist/images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Логотип Рофас"></a>
      <div class="lang">RU
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1 pure-u-md-11-12 pure-u-lg-11-12">
    <div class="slider pure-g">
      <div id="roof" class="slider-content pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-2">
        <div class="slider_content">
          <span>01</span>
          <div class="slider-text">
            <h1>Rofas <span>Roof</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis </p>
          </div>
          <a href="index.html" class="btn-roof"><i class="fa fa-undo fa-lg fa-rotate-90" style="color:#e64e4e"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-right pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-2">
        <div class="object-container">
          <div class="all">
            <div class="for-all first"></div>
            <div class="for-all second"></div>
            <div class="for-all third"></div>
            <div class="for-all fourth"></div>
            <div class="for-all fifth"></div>
            <div class="for-all sixth"></div>
            <div class="for-all seventh"></div>
            <div class="for-all eigth"></div>
            <div class="for-all nineth"></div>
            <div class="for-all tenth"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="right-side">
            <a href="index.html" class="btn"><img src="./src/icons/return.png"></a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" style="margin-top: 10vh"><img src="./src/icons/speaker.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Страница](http://mysolaris.xyz/slide1.html)

Comment: Так надо? http://lepimivarim.kagg.eu/menu/

Comment: @KAGGDesign да, шикарно!

Comment: Я чуть позже кину сюда выжимку из кода на этом сайтике

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено: блоку object-container задано overflow: auto, а блоку all - подогнана высота (у меня 390-400%). Благодарю @KAGG DESIGN за наводку

Comment: OK, у меня времени не было ответить подробно